# How to programmatically add a new contact to the iOS device from a PC/Mac

Tags: python, ios, iphone

I need a way to programmatically add a new contact to iPhone from a computer.
Preferably using Python.

Long story short, I have contacts extracted from my old phone, and I want to transfer them to my new iPhone.

A solution that comes to my mind is to fill an addressbook supported by iTunes and then synchronize it with iOS.

But I would like a clean, easy, direct approach over intermixing this and that to find out that it wouldn't work because of something idiotic popped up.

Is there any protocol specification for doing that, or a way to link to iTunes DLLs or dynlibs?

Or perhaps a tweak using Apple Script on Mac.

Comment: I don't think your desired approach is the best; still: the procedure the Genius Bar always used (when I was one, anyway) was to create a new, empty address book in Address Book. Import the contacts if they're in CSV format and turn them into a vCard file. You can then either sync contacts through iTunes or export a vCard file, email it to yourself, and open it on the phone to merge them into the phone's address book. If they're already a vCard skip straight to emailing the file to the phone.

Comment: Is there a specification of vCard file. I.e. Can I create it myself directly without involving addressbooks etc. But I don't see why wouldn't be possible to add a contact directly to the device. Symbian OS allows you contact manipulations from a PC via USB or Bluetooth. So iOS should too. There are some third-party software out there claiming they are for backup and data transition and that they work. So if they can talk to iOS via USB then it is safe to conclude that what I want is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my personal problem by constructing vCard file containing all contacts from my old phone, then transfering that file to my iPhone manually who happily offered to import all contacts from it into its contacts App.

VCard specification can be found on Wikipedia. It is one nice file format. I used version 2.1 and it worked.

I was afraid that iPhone would accept only XML vCard version, but it worked with 2.1.
That's what I really meant in my comment. I wasn't sure which vCard version iOS uses.

It was extremely easy as my old phone gave me all contacts as a bunch of individual vCard files. So I only needed a simple little program to combine them into one file.

Thanks to apraetor for a comment that gave me that idea.

But the way I wanted it done (as I explained in the question) is possible by using LibIMobileDevice library available at:

http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

I didn't have time to experiment but it should work. And anyone searching for a way to do what I wanted should know about this excellent library.

I'd like someone's answer with details on how it is done and the code (for other's benefit), as I wouldn't play with this for some time. I am currently very busy.

I suspect it is something like:

1. Get all contacts from iPhone
2. Add new ones or delete old ones
3. Synchronize back

as I didn't see anything 
there hinting at direct contact manipulation.